# White page showing before app load

Tags: cordova, mobile, hybrid

White page showing before app load in android cordova application?

please can any help me how to remove this white page.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably splash-screen and you must have deleted default splash-screen images. 
But you should provide more info about your problem.

Consult documentation for that here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/config_ref_images.md.html

Comment: when ever i open my app for first time blank white screen displaying and then splash-screen is opening .....

Comment: You need to provide more info we can only guess whats wrong this way. What framework are you using?

Comment: i am using jquery mobile